# height from list items

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a list inside. I want to know what's the css property to control the space between the lines from the same list item.

[image]

Comment: you could try line-height

Comment: are you sure ? You need `js` to solve this issue ? @edbird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, set your div a valid id.

Next, use Javascript:

```
    var element = document.getElementById('<your div ID>'),
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
    height = style.getPropertyValue('height');
```

Wish it would help.

Comment: you don't need to use js for this :/

Comment: okay u win if html can process a block of logic code and return values :) @NabeelKhan

Answer (score 2):

As you're using list items `<li>`, you can use this code to give your each list item a height:

```
li {
    height: 100px;
}
```

You can also give your div a specific id or class and then use it as reference too so that not all `li` in your code get that style applied.

You can also give each li a class too.

E.g.:

```
li.myclass {
    height: 100px;
}
```

jsfiddle for this: https://jsfiddle.net/rmnd22uh/

```css
li{
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>first item</li>
    <li>second item</li>
    <li>third item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I hope this helps.

P.S. you need to learn a lot about html / css, so start learning from w3schools or any other resource.

Answer (score 1):

Try line-height for the list items. The line-height property specifies the height of a line. So by adding this css property, you could get what you require.

Sample code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      ul li{
        line-height:50px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>text1</li>
      <li>text2</li>
      <li>text3</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

demo fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/melvinstanly/oud2jab5/2/)